# OCR using Kivy and Screenmanager issue passing variable between screens

Tags: python, attributes, kivy, ocr, python-tesseract

I am building an OCR application for visually impaired users. I'm wanting the app to open straight away onto the camera screen, when the user takes a pic on button press I want ocr process to occur and display the output on the text screen in a lbl or txtbox and have a TTS read out what the text says. My issue is that i am having trouble obtaining the output of ocr and displaying it, I'm not familiar with screenmanager or python. ideally the opencv and tesseract process would occur in same function as the capture however i cant get the output recognised on the following screen. heres some code, any suggestions and help appreciated!

```
# Importing the libraries
import cv2
import pytesseract

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'D:/pytesseract/tesseract.exe'


# voice_text = ""
# for i in ocrtext.split():
# voice_text += i + ' '

# voice_text = voice_text[:-1]
# voice_text
# engine = pyttsx3.init()
# engine.setProperty("rate", 145)
# voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
# engine.say(voice_text)
# engine.runAndWait()


class CameraScreen(Screen):
    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        camera.export_to_png("./picforocr.png")
        image = cv2.imread("./picforocr.png")
        ocrtext = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)


class TextScreen(Screen):
    pass


GUI = Builder.load_string("""

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        CameraScreen:
            name: "camera_screen"
            id: camera_screen
        TextScreen:
            name: "text_screen"
            id: text_screen



<CameraScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Camera:
            id: camera
            resolution: (800, 800)
        Button:
            text: 'OCR!'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
            on_press:
                root.capture()
                # root refers to <CameraScreen>
                # app refers to TestCamera, app.root refers to the GridLayout: at the top
                app.root.ids['screen_manager'].transition.direction = 'left'
                app.root.ids['screen_manager'].current = 'text_screen'

<TextScreen>:
    Label:
        id: ocr_output
        text:
            Camerascreen.ocrtext
        font_size: 20
    Button:
        text: "Do OCR Again"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        font_size: 50
        on_press:
            app.root.ids['screen_manager'].transition.direction = 'right'
            app.root.ids['screen_manager'].current = 'camera_screen'
            
""")


class MyOCRApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return GUI

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyOCRApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basic code for passing texts from one class to another and also `TextInput` data. This is `python` code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

class FirstPage(FloatLayout):

    def switch_screen(self):
        secondpage = self.login_name = self.ids.login_name.text
        myapp.secondpage.update_name1(secondpage)
        secondpage = self.password_name = self.ids.password_name.text
        myapp.secondpage.update_name2(secondpage)
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'SecondPage'

class SecondPage(FloatLayout):

    def switch_back(self):
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='right', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'FirstPage'

    def update_name1(self, name_login):
        self.ids.name_login.text = (f'{name_login}:')

    def update_name2(self, name_password):
        self.ids.name_password.text = (f'{name_password}:')

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.firstpage = FirstPage()
        screen = Screen(name='FirstPage')
        screen.add_widget(self.firstpage)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.secondpage = SecondPage()
        screen = Screen(name='SecondPage')
        screen.add_widget(self.secondpage)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager

myapp = MyApp()
myapp.run()
```

And this is `kivy` code:

```
FirstPage:

<FirstPage>:

    TextInput:
        id: login_name
        size_hint: .65, .08
        multiline: False
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .57}

    TextInput:
        id: password_name
        size_hint: .65, .08
        multiline: False
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .47}

    Button:
        text: "First"
        size_hint: .1, .1
        on_release: root.switch_screen()

<SecondPage>:

    Button:
        text: "Second"
        size_hint: .1, .1
        on_release: root.switch_back()

    Label:
        id: name_login
        text: "Login"
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .57}

    Label:
        id: name_password
        text: "Password"
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .47}
```